# Select text when clicked on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

So far I have this:

```
<span class="description">Description 1</span>
<button class="select">Select!</button>

<span class="description">Description 2</span>
<button class="select">Select!</button>

<span class="description">Description 3</span>
<button class="select">Select!</button>

<span class="description">Description 4</span>
<button class="select">Select!</button>
```

I want button to select text inside "description" class element, but only for previous one. Is that possible? Aka if user clicks on first select button, Description 1 will be selected.

Note: In selection I mean that the text should be highlighted. Thanks in advance

Comment: Code so short, mistakes so many! Uff!

Comment: I just copy pasted text several times and didn't look at ID, so sorry about multiple IDs

Answer (score 2):

Use `prev()` to get the previous element:

```
 $("button").click(function(){
      var text = $(this).prev().text();
      alert(text);
 });
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maxdK/

Comment: Great, thanks but I want it to highlight the text, not alert it. So that user can right click and copy selected text

Comment: @GeorgeLubaretsi, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse

Comment: @GeorgeLubaretsi This answers your question, your question doesn't mention that text should be highlighted. you can simply delete the alert part.

Answer (score 1):

To highlight the text you can change the style of text or can apply any css attribute like 
     $(this).prev().css("background-color","red");

or you can add any css

```
$(this).prev().addClass("css-class");
```